# Getting more than one number after specific string

Tags: python, arrays, list, numbers, integer

I have problem getting numbers from list after 'RND':

```
myList = [['1123-TDT', '10593917/5422', 'RND', '20.5', 'QWTQWGSAG', 'RND', '40'],
          ['1156-TDT', '51205915/6166', 'ASDWT', '111551', 'RND', '35']]
```

I can get number after RND if there is only one RND in list item(myList[1]). But if there's two of 'em(myList[0]), then nothing happens.

Example of what I have:

```
myList = [['1123-TDT', '10593917/5422', 'RND', '20.5', 'QWTQWGSAG', 'RND', '40'],
          ['1156-TDT', '51205915/6166', 'ASDWT', '111551', 'RND', '35']]

listLen = len(myList)

for x in range(listLen):
    if 'RND' in myList[x]:
        y = myList[x].index('RND')
        z = myList[x][y+1]
        print(z)
```

Output looks like that:

```
20.5
35
```

But I would like it to be:

```
20.5 40
35
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `list.index` will only give *the first index*; you will have to iterate if there are multiple possible options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access each sublist and each sub element in the sublists then get the element at the index after the current if the current element  is equal to `"RND"`:

```
print( [sub[ind] for sub in myList for ind, ele in enumerate(sub,1) if ele == "RND"])
['20.5', '40', '35']
```

Using two normal loops:

```
# iterate over each sublist
for sub in myList: 
    # check every element in each sublist for "RND"
    # if we find a match print the next element in the list
    for ind, ele in enumerate(sub,1):
        if ele == "RND":
            print(sub[ind])
```

We use `enumerate(sub,1)` where 1 is the start index so when we access `sub[ind]` we get the next element instead of the current if we used a start index of `0`.

`y = myList[x].index('RND')` gets you only the **first** occurrence.

If you want the output printed on a single line for each sublist use `end=" "`:

```
for sub in myList:
    # check every element in each sublist for "RND"
    # if we find a match print the next element in the list
    for ind, ele in enumerate(sub,1):
        if ele == "RND":
            print(sub[ind],end=" ")
    print()
20.5 40 
35
```

Comment: Is this not going to do an infinite looping?

Comment: @bcesars, why would you think that?

Comment: Because you didn't set recursive to `false` right after `for` statement, passing through these sublists.

Comment: @bcesars, what is recursive? There is no recursion anywhere, we are iterating over lists

Comment: Ok. But I'm afraid if is there possibility this script start over again right after finish sweeping?

Comment: @bcesars, no, the code ends when we reach the last element of the last sublist.

Comment: Thank you again for fast response! But there is still a problem, I need it to be inside (for in range) loop... So it will repeat the results many times. Any way to fix this?

Comment: put the whole code in another loop so basically another outer loop in range of how many times you want to repeat  it for. is that what you mean?

Comment: I want it to run through only once. But since I have like 4000 lines of text or so, it starts repeating everything. Don't know if you can understand me.. :p But thank you very much for helping!

Comment: lol not sure I do, can you give me an example of what is repeating?

Comment: I would like to see only those RND-s numbers, which have met a condition.. for example: myList[x][x] == '1123-TDT'.. At the moment it shows all list items RND numbers. Bit better? ;p

Comment: lol yes,  just add whatever conditions you want, `elif ele == '1123-TDT':print(sub[ind])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through your respective lists within your list, to accomplish this with your approach. 
Maybe try iterating through your list elements for each list, checking whether the list element is equal to `RND`, and printing the following indexed value as you currently are doing.
 The only change you would have to make is iterating through your list elements and using a conditional statement to find `RND` instead of just using `list.index` to determine the index of `RND`. This would be a good exercise for you to do yourself.